# How to use load and open in same div

Tags: jquery

I'm a newbie. I have tried and made a research on the web regarding this case but I am still unable to produce it.

My question is,
lets say I have a page that shows records of staff leaves. That record can be sorted with `In Progress`, `Approve` and `Not Approve`. I'm using load, e.g. when user chooses `Approve`, it will load `result.php` inside a `div` & shows `Approve` status only.

The problem is I have other links on `result.php` page but whenever a user clicks on the links, it goes to the new page but not inside the `div` content. I want the link to load inside the same `div` as well.

update with coding:

```
`$("#button_name").click(function(event){
```

var sort = $("#sort").val();
$("#content").load('result.php', {"sort":sort});
});`

I use this on my record.php page and it can display what i need in the content div.

on my result.php, i have this link:

`<a id="record" href="result.php?startrow='($startrow+30).'&sort='.$sort.'">Next</a>';`

it's a link to go to next and also there is a link for previous record. how do I want it to display inside the content div as well

Comment: You need to use AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have understood your problem, to load a link into that div you have to make an AJAX request to that URL and after you have got the response from that AJAX request, just replace the new content with that DIV.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Do i have to use get?

Comment: Yes you can use GET method also.